# Dispatch metadata from WordPress DB query into a table with 4 columns

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, html-table, modulo

I have a variable (array) and is returning the following:

```
array(13) { 
    ["meta_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["post_id"]=> string(4) "2112"
    ["provider"]=> string(12) "Abc news"
    ["scheme"]=> string(3) "morning"
    ["viewers"]=> string(9) "2000"
    ["min_time"]=> string(3) "5"
    ["max_time"]=> string(3) "100"
    ["bways"]=> string(2) "10"
    ["release_date"]=> string(10) "04-05-2021"
    ["type"]=> string(11) "Video"
    ["variance"]=> string(4) "4k"
    ["tech"]=> string(9) "JS, HTML5"
    ["game_id"]=> string(5) "17640" 
}
```

I get this data from the following query:

```php
$meta = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE post_id = %d
", $post_id), ARRAY_A);
```

Currently, I am outputting the data in a table using something like:

```php
$output .="<tr>";
$output .= sprintf('<td>%s</td><td>%s</td>', $attribute, $value);
$output .="</tr>";
```

and it is generating a table with 2 columns. I want to have a 4 columns instead like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Left column with a maximum of 5 rows and the remaining rows on the other column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this data array:

```php
$meta = [
    "meta_id" => "2",
    "post_id" => "2112", 
    "provider" => "Abc news", 
    "scheme" => "morning", 
    "viewers" => "2000", 
    "min_time" =>  "5", 
    "max_time" =>  "100", 
    "bways" =>  "10", 
    "release_date" => "04-05-2021", 
    "type" => "Video", 
    "variance" => "4k", 
    "tech" => "JS, HTML5", 
    "game_id" => "17640", 
];
```

You can use the ["Modulo" operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to get the data dispatched in a table with 4 columns like:

```php
$index = 0; // Initializing
$count = count($meta);

$output = '<table>
<tr><th>Attribute</th><th>Value</th><th>Attribute</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr>';

// Loop through array keys / values
foreach ( $meta as $attribute => $value ) {
    $output .= sprintf('<td>%s</td><td>%s</td>', $attribute, $value);
    $output .= $index % 2 === 0 && ($count - 1) === $index ? '<td></td><td></td>' : '';
    $output .= $index % 2 === 1 ? '</tr><tr>' : '';

    $index++;
}
echo $output . '</tr>
</table>';
```

It should work as expected. you will get somethiing like:

[image]